# Optimizing my algorithm for multiplication modulo

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization, multiplication

I have a problem from the internet where i have an array of N integers and have to perform segment multiplication some T times given the left(L) and right segment(R) of the array and return the answer modulo some given modulus(M).

Constraints

N,T<=100000

1<=L<=R<=N

M<=10^9

and integers <=100

Ex-

input

5(N)
2 5 8 9 4 
4(T)
1 2 3
2 3 4
1 1 1
1 5 100000

output

1
0
0
2880

So i have made a solution to this problem but it is a little slow i need  tips to optimize my program.

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void)
{
        int t;
        scanf("%d",&t);

        int Array[t+1];


    for (int i = 1; i <=t; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&Array[i]);
    }

    int N;
    scanf("%d",&N);


    for (int i = 0; i <N ; i++)
    {

        long long a,b,c;
        scanf("%lld%lld%lld",&a,&b,&c);
        long long Product = 1;
        if (c==1)
        {
            Product = 0;

        }
        else
        {

            for (int j = a; j <=b ; j++)
            {

                Product *= Array[j];

                if (Product>=10000000000000000)
                {
                    Product%=c;
                }
            }

        }

        Product%=c;


        printf("%lld\n",Product );

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: side:  suggest  `Array[0] = 0;` before `int N;`.

Comment: @chux why? i am not going to use Array[0]

Comment: So if N=100000 you just put input to scanf a 100000 times? That is why it is slow?

Comment: That part actually doesn't count towards the time

Comment: @admin: this question is a part of running contest. http://www.codechef.com/AUG13/problems/CHMOD

Comment: @rspr It's not our function to police whether or not people use this site to help them with contests.

Comment: @ George Stocker you are right from you side. But many of the time I have experienced that moderators have set examples to avoid such practices, many of such posts are blocked in the past too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### HINTS

You could compute an array A_p[i] for each prime p less than 100 that notes how many times p divides the i^th entry of your array.

Then you can compute a secondary array B_p[j] which is the cumulative sum of A_p[i] for i up to and including j.  (This can be done in O(n) by the recursion B_p[i]=B_p[i-1]+A_p[i].)

This secondary array will allow you to compute the total power of each prime in any range.  For example, if you wanted to know how many times the prime 5 appeared in array entries 10 to 100 you can compute B_5[100]-B_5[10-1].

So for each query you can then compute the final answer by raising each prime to the corresponding power and multiplying the results together modulo M.  Note that there is a technique called [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) that makes this calculation efficient.

If 0 is a possible integer, then add 0 to your list of primes that are considered in the calculation.

### FOR INTEREST

Note that this approach of using a cumulative sum is quite useful in many situations.  For example, the [Viola-Jones method for face recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework) uses a version of this technique in 2 dimensions in order to be able to compute 2d filters efficiently.

Comment: this question is part of the running contest. Find the link here [link](http://www.codechef.com/AUG13/problems/CHMOD) I request to delete your answer. I have requested the admin too to block the post.

Comment: I tried, but Stack overflow refuses to let me delete an accepted answer.